# How can I access variable stored outside of controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to save the model id that is being saved and avoid another save while it's saving it, but I don't know how to persist data between requests and access it later.

**JAVASCRIPT**
*Works perfectly well, but I can't do the same in **LARAVEL 9**.*

```
// MODELS THAT ARE BEING UPDATED.
const models = {}

function handleRequest(req) {
  if (models[req.model_id]) {
    return
  }

  models[req.model_id] = true
  // UPDATE MODEL.
  models[req.model_id] = false
}
```

**LARAVEL 9**
*Doesn't work as expected.*

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

// MODELS THAT ARE BEING UPDATED.
$models = [];

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    if ($models[$model_id]) {
      return;
    }
    
    $models[$model_id] = true;
    // UPDATE MODEL.
    $models[$model_id] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add that global keyword then for PHP to look into global scope. If I were you, I would have used sessions rather.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to compare different entities in JS, you use a Function, and in Laravel you have a Class, these are different concepts and mechanics of work

You can make a property inside a class

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  // MODELS THAT ARE BEING UPDATED.
  public $models = [];
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    if ($this->models[$model_id]) {
      return;
    }
    
    $this->models[$model_id] = true;
    // UPDATE MODEL.
    $this->models[$model_id] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: $this->models doesn't persist data between different requests

Comment: I'm probably telling you but PHP doesn't work like that, it only lives during a request, after which everything dies, You can use a database or other tools to save data between requests

Comment: Your can use Cache, Redis, or Simple file with JSON 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using sessions:

```
session(['model_id' => 123]); // save data to session

$model_id = session('model_id'); // get data from session
```

Comment: Can you tell if ```session(['model_id' => 123])``` is shared between any user?

Comment: @Misael Session data is scoped to a session which is on a user basis.